# How to set record type of records while saving the records?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have  a vf page and its extensions,I am trying to save the multiple lists of a object against a particular recordtype.But i am unable to fetch the record the record type and then assign to the same object.If you have any idea and then please mention it.Thank you.

```
public with sharing class LevittAmpBudgetUpdatedCtrl {
     public List<Grant_Report__c> grExpenseObjLst{get;set;}
     public List<Grant_Report__c> grCashObjLst{get;set;}//Matching fund,Cash Object List
     public List<Grant_Report__c> grInKindObjLst{get;set;}//Matching fund,inkind Object List
     public Grant_Report__c grObj{get;set;}
     public Grant_Approval__c gaObj{get;set;}
     private ID ids{get;set;}

     public LevittAmpBudgetUpdatedCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
         //
        ids= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); //
        gaObj=new Grant_Approval__c();
        grExpenseObjLst= new list<Grant_Report__c>();        
        grCashObjLst=new List<Grant_Report__c>();
        grInKindObjLst=new List<Grant_Report__c>();

        RecordType rt= [SELECT id FROM RecordType WHERE Name='Matching Fund Cash'];
        System.debug('ssssss'+rt);

         for(AMP_Budget_Expense__c exObj:AMP_Budget_Expense__c.getAll().Values()){
                        grObj=new Grant_Report__c();
                        grObj.Expense_Category_Label__c=exObj.Expense_Category__c;
                        grExpenseObjLst.add(grObj);    
                    }              
          //check if id is not null
       if(ids!= null)
          {

                gaObj = [SELECT id,AMP_Grant_Request_Amount__c,Cash_Match_Total_Amount__c,
                                InKind_Match_Total_Amount__c,Comment__c FROM Grant_Approval__c WHERE Id= :ids];//   
                for(Grant_Report__c gr: [select id,Matching_Cash_Source__c,Matching_Cash_Amount__c,Matching_Cash_Commitment__c from Grant_Report__c where Grant_Approval__c=:ids ]) {//get all related grant report cash records
                     grCashObjLst.add(gr);               
                }
                for(Grant_Report__c gr: [select id,Matching_inKind_Source__c,Matching_inKind_item__c,Matching_inKind_Amount__c, 
                                               Matching_inKind_Commitment__c from Grant_Report__c where Grant_Approval__c=:ids ]) {//get all related grant report IN-Kind records
                     grInKindObjLst.add(gr);                 
                }
                for(Grant_Report__c gr: [select id,Expense_Total_Amount__c,Expense_Cash_Amount__c,Expense_InKind_Anount__c,Expense_Category_Label__c from Grant_Report__c where Grant_Approval__c=:ids ]) {//get all related grant report IN-Kind records
                     grExpenseObjLst.add(gr);                 
                }
             }
         else{   
                //default 5 lineitem will come
                    for(integer i=0; i<5; i++)
                    {
                        grObj = new Grant_Report__c();
                        grCashObjLst.add(grObj);
                        grInKindObjLst.add(grObj); 
                    }

             }

    }

     //add more row of Matching Funds,Cash
     public pageReference addMoreCashFund(){
         grObj = new Grant_Report__c();
                grCashObjLst.add(grObj);
                return null; 
     }
     //add more row of Matching Funds,Cash
     public pageReference addMoreInkindFund(){
         grObj = new Grant_Report__c();
                grInKindObjLst.add(grObj);
                return null; 
     }

     Public Pagereference savedoc(){
        List<Grant_Report__c> enteredCashGrantReport = new List<Grant_Report__c>();
        List<Grant_Report__c> enteredInKindGrantReport = new List<Grant_Report__c>();  
        List<Grant_Report__c> enteredExpenseReport = new List<Grant_Report__c>();       
        for(Grant_Report__c gr: grCashObjLst){
                 if(gr.id==null)
                   {
                      gr.Grant_Approval__c= ids;
                   }
                 enteredCashGrantReport.add(gr);
          }
         for(Grant_Report__c gr: grInKindObjLst){
                 if(gr.id==null)
                   {
                      gr.Grant_Approval__c= ids;
                   }
                 enteredInKindGrantReport.add(gr);
           }
           for(Grant_Report__c gr: grExpenseObjLst){
                 if(gr.id==null)
                   {
                      gr.Grant_Approval__c= ids;
                   }
                 enteredExpenseReport.add(gr);                 
           }
           grExpenseObjLst=null;
          try{ 
               upsert gaObj;
               upsert enteredCashGrantReport; 
               upsert enteredInKindGrantReport; 
               upsert enteredExpenseReport;              
          }catch(System.DMLException e) {
                ApexPages.addMessages(e);
                return null;
           }  
        return NULL;
      }
      public PageReference Back() 
        {
            PageReference startPage=new PageReference('/apex/Network_Calendar');
            startPage.setRedirect(true);
            return  startPage;
        }

}
```

Comment: if my answer is not what you are looking for, please add code to your question so we can see what did you attempted, and why it's not working.

Comment: I posted my code.please check

Comment: So you want to assign the `Matching Fund Cash` record type to records in which of the lists in your code?

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to add the `Matching Fund Cash` record type to the records before `upserting` them in your `savedoc()` method. If that's the case, checkout my updated answer.

Comment: yes..thats right

Comment: Cool. So, replace your `savedoc()` method with mine below, and let us know if it worked?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> **SUMMER '18 UPDATE**
>
> You can now use the `getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()` to get a Record Type Id by Developer Name without spending a SOQL query. This should be the preferred approach going forward instead of using the old `getRecordTypeInfosByName()` method as suggested in the original answer.

Use this approach instead of the old suggestion below, unless you are really trying to get the Record Type Id by `RECORD_TYPE_NAME` (Label). The rest of the answer still applies:

```
Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.OBJECT_NAME.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()
                      .get('RECORD_TYPE_DEVELOPER_NAME').getRecordTypeId();
```

---

You can obtain a Record Type in code in the following way:

```
Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.OBJECT_NAME.getRecordTypeInfosByName()
                  .get('RECORD_TYPE_NAME').getRecordTypeId();
```

Just replace the `OBJECT_NAME` with your object (e.g - `Account`), and the `RECORD_TYPE_NAME` with the record type name for that object.

In order to assign this Record Type to a specific record you can use the `RecordTypeId` field. Here's an example for `Account`:

```
Account acc = new Account(Name='Test Account', RecordTypeId = recordTypeId);
```

or through a property like this:

```
acc.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;
```

**UPDATE**

In your case you can obtain the `recordTypeId` like this:

```
Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Grant_Report__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName()
                  .get('Matching Fund Cash').getRecordTypeId();
```

And then just assign this `recordTypeId` to `RecordTypeId` field of the records in your `FOR` loops that you need to update. I'm assuming that's in the `saveDoc()` method:

```
 Public Pagereference savedoc(){
    Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Grant_Report__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName()
                  .get('Matching Fund Cash').getRecordTypeId();

    List<Grant_Report__c> allGrantReports = new List<Grant_Report__c>();

    for(Grant_Report__c gr: grCashObjLst){
             if(gr.id==null)
             {
                  gr.Grant_Approval__c= ids;                   
             }
             gr.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;//assign record type
             allGrantReports.add(gr);
     }
     for(Grant_Report__c gr: grInKindObjLst){
             if(gr.id==null)
             {
                gr.Grant_Approval__c= ids;
             }
             gr.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;//assign record type
             allGrantReports.add(gr);
     }
     for(Grant_Report__c gr: grExpenseObjLst){
             if(gr.id==null)
             {
                gr.Grant_Approval__c= ids;
             }
             gr.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;//assign record type
             allGrantReports.add(gr);                 
     }
     grExpenseObjLst=null;
     try{ 
           upsert gaObj;          
           //saved you 2 DML statements here by joining 3 lists to 1
           upsert allGrantReports ;          
     }catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
       }  
    return NULL;
  }
```

**UPDATE 2**

NOTE: No need to use this approach after Summer '18 update

In case you want to get Record Type by developer name, you'll have to use a DML statement:

```
Id recordTypeId = [select Id from RecordType where DeveloperName = 'Matching_Fund_Cash' AND sObjectType = 'Grant_Report__c' limit 1].Id;
```

Comment: Can you add the assign part i.e. setting the `RecordTypeId` to the answer?

Comment: @KeithC Better? :)

Comment: Yep - +1 from me.

Comment: Now,I want to get recordType by DeveloperName instead of RecordTypeInfosByName because recordTypeByName is not for all future cases.Is there any method to get developerName??

Comment: @VickySingh see my Update 2 for DeveloperName record type.

Comment: I would suggest to add a criteria on SObjectType.
Then,
Id recordTypeId = [select Id from RecordType where DeveloperName = 'RECORD_TYPE_NAME' AND SObjectType='OBJECT_NAME' limit 1].Id;

Comment: @user56303 Good spot. I updated my answer. Although, that approach shouldn't really be used anymore after Summer '18 Update.

Answer (score -1):

```
public with sharing class LevittAmpBudgetUpdatedCtrl {
 public List<Grant_Report__c> grExpenseObjLst{get;set;}
 public List<Grant_Report__c> grCashObjLst{get;set;}//Matching fund,Cash Object List
 public List<Grant_Report__c> grInKindObjLst{get;set;}//Matching fund,inkind Object List
 public Grant_Report__c grObj{get;set;}
 public Grant_Approval__c gaObj{get;set;}
 private ID ids{get;set;}

 public LevittAmpBudgetUpdatedCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     //
    ids= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); //
    gaObj=new Grant_Approval__c();
    grExpenseObjLst= new list<Grant_Report__c>();        
    grCashObjLst=new List<Grant_Report__c>();
    grInKindObjLst=new List<Grant_Report__c>();

    RecordType rt= [SELECT id FROM RecordType WHERE Name='Matching Fund Cash'];
    System.debug('ssssss'+rt);

     for(AMP_Budget_Expense__c exObj:AMP_Budget_Expense__c.getAll().Values()){
                    grObj=new Grant_Report__c();
                    grObj.Expense_Category_Label__c=exObj.Expense_Category__c;
                    grExpenseObjLst.add(grObj);    
                }              
      //check if id is not null
   if(ids!= null)
      {

            gaObj = [SELECT id,AMP_Grant_Request_Amount__c,Cash_Match_Total_Amount__c,
                            InKind_Match_Total_Amount__c,Comment__c FROM Grant_Approval__c WHERE Id= :ids];//   
            for(Grant_Report__c gr: [select id,Matching_Cash_Source__c,Matching_Cash_Amount__c,Matching_Cash_Commitment__c from Grant_Report__c where Grant_Approval__c=:ids ]) {//get all related grant report cash records
                 grCashObjLst.add(gr);               
            }
            for(Grant_Report__c gr: [select id,Matching_inKind_Source__c,Matching_inKind_item__c,Matching_inKind_Amount__c, 
                                           Matching_inKind_Commitment__c from Grant_Report__c where Grant_Approval__c=:ids ]) {//get all related grant report IN-Kind records
                 grInKindObjLst.add(gr);                 
            }
            for(Grant_Report__c gr: [select id,Expense_Total_Amount__c,Expense_Cash_Amount__c,Expense_InKind_Anount__c,Expense_Category_Label__c from Grant_Report__c where Grant_Approval__c=:ids ]) {//get all related grant report IN-Kind records
                 grExpenseObjLst.add(gr);                 
            }
         }
     else{   
            //default 5 lineitem will come
                for(integer i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    grObj = new Grant_Report__c();
                    grCashObjLst.add(grObj);
                    grInKindObjLst.add(grObj); 
                }

         }

}

 //add more row of Matching Funds,Cash
 public pageReference addMoreCashFund(){
     grObj = new Grant_Report__c();
            grCashObjLst.add(grObj);
            return null; 
 }
 //add more row of Matching Funds,Cash
 public pageReference addMoreInkindFund(){
     grObj = new Grant_Report__c();
            grInKindObjLst.add(grObj);
            return null; 
 }

 Public Pagereference savedoc(){
    List<Grant_Report__c> enteredCashGrantReport = new List<Grant_Report__c>();
    List<Grant_Report__c> enteredInKindGrantReport = new List<Grant_Report__c>();  
    List<Grant_Report__c> enteredExpenseReport = new List<Grant_Report__c>();       
    for(Grant_Report__c gr: grCashObjLst){
             if(gr.id==null)
               {
                  gr.Grant_Approval__c= ids;
               }
             enteredCashGrantReport.add(gr);
      }
     for(Grant_Report__c gr: grInKindObjLst){
             if(gr.id==null)
               {
                  gr.Grant_Approval__c= ids;
               }
             enteredInKindGrantReport.add(gr);
       }
       for(Grant_Report__c gr: grExpenseObjLst){
             if(gr.id==null)
               {
                  gr.Grant_Approval__c= ids;
               }
             enteredExpenseReport.add(gr);                 
       }
       grExpenseObjLst=null;
      try{ 
           upsert gaObj;
           upsert enteredCashGrantReport; 
           upsert enteredInKindGrantReport; 
           upsert enteredExpenseReport;              
      }catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
       }  
    return NULL;
  }
  public PageReference Back() 
    {
        PageReference startPage=new PageReference('/apex/Network_Calendar');
        startPage.setRedirect(true);
        return  startPage;
    }
```

}

Comment: is it an answer or question ?

Comment: Thats my code..its not the answer.