# DEBUG|Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for restricted picklist field

Tags: apex, picklist, email2case, apextestrunresult

I have a record type picklist on Case object.
When I create case via email-to-case that works fine without any issue(I have some APEX code related to that)

Issue:
The problem is when I write test cases for that and run the test that says on insert and update.

> DEBUG|Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for restricted picklist field

What is the issue? Even though that works fine when I create case via email-to-case.

Code:

```
Case newCase = new Case();
newCase.Origin = 'Email';
newCase.Subject = 'Subject';
newCase.OwnerId = System.Label.Default_Case_Owner_Queue;
newCase.Status = 'New';
newCase.Priority = 'Medium';
newCase.Description = 'This is a new case';
newCase.Type = 'Invoicing';
newCase.Email__c  = 'email@test.fi';
newCase.Close_Code__c = 'test'; // this is the picklist which is causing issue, the picklist value was already added to record type.
insert newCase;
```

How can I fix that to pass the tests?
TIA

Comment: Can you check API name for the picklist, sometime that can be different. And try to copy paste the API name and use it in the test block.

Comment: You may have to set the record type while insert. In your code we do not see the record type assignment.

Comment: How can I consider record type in the code? I assumed this is the record type code newCase.Type = 'Invoicing';

Comment: So the record type was the issue. I added that and now it works fine. Please add as answer then I will accept the answer. Record type code adding by following this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/141101/85098

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the insert the record type assignment is missing and the default record type may not have the picklist value that you are trying to insert with, so add the record type assignment-

```java
Case newCase = new Case();
...
newCase.RecordTypeId = '{get value from describe call}';
newCase.Close_Code__c = 'test';
insert newCase;
```